# Openstack-Swift Disk usage for Containers

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, disk-space-utilization, openstack

Currently i am testing a openstack-swift cluster made of 1 proxy node and 6 storage nodes. Each host has ubuntu 12.04. I put 5000 containers each having a text 4.6 KB. Each storage node has a 100 GB disk mounted and formatted as a xfs partition. After the test when i check disk usage on the storage nodes i came acroos a strange behaviour.

Mount point: /srv/node/sdb1

- 2.0M  accounts
- 2.5G  containers
- 40M   objects
- 0 tmp

As you can containers directory  having only db files for indexing takes too much space. Anyone come across this kind of behaviour before? What can be the reason for containers using this much space?

Comment: What is your `df -h` output?

Comment: /dev/sdb1       100G  2.5G   98G   3% /srv/node/sdb1

Answer (score 0):

@fga

Were you able to find reason for this? 
You can also try out [ssbench](https://github.com/swiftstack/ssbench) to find out what is happening with your cluster. I would hope it will be helpful to your analysis.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.For tests sofar i have been using tsung. But i have heard of ssbench and been planning to run another test with version grizzly soon.